# model for general artificial intelligence in today's deep-learning and computational neroscience community

Tags: deep-learning, neuroscience

I've follwed recent DL's proceed from NIPS.
Although i haven't track what happens in Computational Neuroscience(CN)'s field.

But I wonder why so little work about general artificial intellgence(GAI)?for example, kinds of network of hebbian to build all supervised/unsupervised/Reinforcement learning.

Or Can anyone tell me what's the state of art about neural networks for GAI, from CN field?Or some review?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean "applications for neural networks" or "how do neural networks work"?

Comment: I think stackexchange would be a more appropriate community for this question.

Comment: @DendiSuhubdy i may misunderstand you ...  for what you say has two meanings(1- Is i new to DL field? or   2-applications or articheture i mean?) 
 As the second question, of course we need both....   No matter what, i think i should review and experiment myself first! Thanks, i may send you my review after i finish it~

Answer (score 0):

All three fields, [Deep Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) (e.g. what you read at NIPS), [Artificial general intelligence (AGI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) and [Computational Neuroscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_neuroscience) are separate fields with some overlap but not too much overlap.

A question like 'what is the state-of-the-art' cannot really be answered in such a general form and would also soon be outdated. You have to be more specific. But just check some sources in the specific field. Wikipedia might be a good start.